# Почему происходит ошибка "Undefined reference to fftwf_malloc" после установки библиотеки fftw3?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, компоновщик

Установил библиотеку `fftw3`. При попытке использовать ее возникает ошибка линкера.

> /home/vadim/projects/test/test3/testFFt/main.cpp:7: error: undefined reference to 'fftwf_malloc'

в `.pro`-файле указал ее, `LIBS += -lfftw3`. Но этого недостаточно, пытался указывать путь через `-L/usr/local/lib/` (по умолчанию библиотека устанавливается туда).

Код программы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fftw3.h>

int main()
{
    float *input = static_cast<float*>(fftwf_malloc(64 * sizeof(float)));
    fftwf_free(input);
    return 0; 
}
```

`.pro`-файл выглядит так:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++17
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/ -lfftw3

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp
```

Comment: может быть это Си-шная библиотека, тогда нужно `extern "C" { #include <fftw3.h> }` *"FFTW is a C subroutine library for computing the discrete Fourier transform"*

Comment: ¿А линкуемая библиотека экспортирует этот символ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы вызываете функцию `fftwf_malloc` - суффкс `f` в `fftwf` намекает, что это функция из библиотеки FFT одинарной точности, то есть `libfftw3f.so`

Поэтому вам нужно установить пакет `libfftw3-single3` (так называется в Debian/Ubuntu) и линковать с библиотекой `-lfftw3f`

Comment: Благодарю! Все верно, как Вы и сказали.